# Apply different styles when select a day - jQuery multidatepicker

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the [multidatepicker plugin](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/).

I have three kind of days on my scope:

1. Unavailable - These ones have the default style;
2. Once a day get a click, it becomes the second kind:
   Out Of Window - These ones have a black border.
3. And, if the day get clicked the second time, the day become last kind: Free - These have a black border and green background.

So, my question is: How to apply an specific style/class on a day when it gets clicked?

I tried something like:

```
onSelect: function(){
    $('.ui-state-active').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('pick_up_free_dayCalendar');    
    })

    $(".calendar_").multiDatesPicker('refresh');
    // multidate picker has no refresh method, I created one!
}
```

feedle: http://jsfiddle.net/TeAKU/

But, didn't work at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle we can play with?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TeAKU/

Comment: I just realized it worked as desired on feedle ... but not here in my localhost. I believe its because I have to generate this calendar dynamically depending on an ajax request which fill out the comparative arrays ... http://jsfiddle.net/TeAKU/

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the problem:

I have to generate those calendars dynamically depending on a dropdown form ... So, it didn't work on the new calendars.

If I use a static calendar, it will work like a charm ...

there's a full working example on feedle ( please, see the link on question)